# Unicode() in python 3

Tags: python, unicode

I have python 2x code which uses unicode() function before searching ascii strings in unicode list. Short of exception catching or evaluating python version, what is the best way to port this code so it works in both python 2 and 3?

Comment: use the six library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

Comment: This trivial superficial problem can be solved by simple means, but the full scope of writing code which is portable between Python 2 and Python 3 is significantly more complex. If you need help with this easy task, I'm guessing you don't even know what the other problems are, and should absolutely read up on 2/3 compatibility before you proceed.  `six` isn't the only game in town, but it's at least a reasonable starting point for learning more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes this dirty hack is enough

```
try:
    unicode
except NameError:
    unicode = str
```

@honi wrote good advice, use [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).